How to enforce Springboot versions from BOM and override it?
I created a SpringBoot project using the initializer for Gradle (using kotlin dsl).
And I added 2 lines to it:

implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.4"))
testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.26.3")

plugins {
    java
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.3.4"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.6"
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(21)
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.4"))  // ADDED THIS
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.26.3")                                 // ADDED THIS
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher")
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

I want to enforce versions from SpringBoot to be used in the parent/bom and be able to override versions.
In my case I can override assertj-core to 3.26.3 as it has newer features that I want to use.
My question comes into play with the plugin id("io.spring.dependency-management") and library implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.4"))
Should I include both? If I remove the plugin all dependencies can still be found but it enforce the version of assertj-core of the bom which is version 3.25.3. How should this be overridden or should I not use the enforcedPlatform? If I remove the enforcedPlatform and there 2 different versions of a library are added (due to transitive dependencies or somrthing), which one will be decided to be used or will the plugin take care of that and how?
I am not sure how these 2 work together or not all.

No you don't need the implementation(enforcedPlatform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:3.3.4"). Gradle will use the version you defined. If you want to override the version specify ext['assertj.version'] = version to use instead of adding a dedicated implementation version. How to override dependencies is also explained in the spring boot documentation.
